# Serialise standard xml envelope containing variable contents

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to create a serialisable class to represent an xml envelope that can contain arbitrary message content. Example xml (simplified) below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <MessageA>
        <Url></Url>
    </MessageA>
</Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <MessageB>
        <Value></Value>
    </MessageB>
</Envelope>
```

My idea is to use a generic envelope class to handle this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope")]
public class Envelope<TContent> where TContent : new()
{
    public Envelope()
    {
        Content = new TContent();
    }
    public TContent Content { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MessageA
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MessageB
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

These could be serialised so:

```
var envelope = new Envelope<MessageA>();
envelope.Content.Url = "http://www.contoso.com";
string xml = envelope.ToXml();
```

However, instead of the xml message that I want (per examples above), I get the following. How can I change the classes or the serialisation process to rename the Content element to the name of the Message itself?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Content>
        <Url>http://www.contoso.com</Url>
    </Content>
</Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the XmlAttributeOverrides class has a solution for this problem. Adding the following method to the Envelope class causes the ToXml() extension method to serialise the object as required.

```
public string ToXml()
{
    return ToXml(typeof(TContent).Name);
}

public string ToXml(string contentElementName)
{
    XmlElementAttribute element = new XmlElementAttribute(contentElementName, typeof(TContent));
    XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
    attributes.XmlElements.Add(element);
    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(typeof(Envelope<TContent>), "Content", attributes);
    return ToXml(this, overrides);
}

public string ToXml(Envelope<TContent> value, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides) 
{
    using (var sw = new Utf8StringWriter())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = omitXmlDeclaration,
            Indent = true
        };
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope<TContent>), overrides);
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```